# swig - c++ to python. link systemd lib

Tags: c++, linux, swig, systemd, linkage

I'm using swig to make a python wrapper for my c/c++ project.

I manage to compile it all but when running python and importing the py file i get

`ImportError: ./_example.so: undefined symbol:sd_bus_get_property_trivial`

I'm using systemd lib
`http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/systemd/chapter06/systemd.html`

in my h file I include the file 
`#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>`

I think the `.so` file for `systemd` lib isn't included automatically with swig, because it's not at the default lib folder. it's at `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so`

How do I include this `.so` file manually? This is my `setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
setup.py file for SWIG simple_ex
"""

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


example_module = Extension('_example',
                           sources=['example_wrap.cxx', 'example.cpp'],
                           extra_compile_args=["-o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so"]
                           )

setup (name = '_example',
       version = '0.1',
       author      = "SWIG Docs",
       ext_modules = [example_module],
       py_modules = ["_example"],
       )
```

`extra_compiled_args=` was some experminet to add the lib. Didn't work.

This is my `.i` file:

```
/* File: example.i */
%module example

%include std_vector.i
%include std_string.i
%include exception.i


%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}

%exception {
    try {
        $action
    } catch(...) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "Unknown exception");
    }
}

int foo(int a);
```

`foo` uses a function from `systemd/sd-bus`

Comment: Why have you written `-o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so` as an extra argument? `-o` is for output, you probably want -l and /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ought to be on the default library path. I think there's a proper way to get distutils to link against dependencies though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this it to use the arguments

```
 runtime_library_dirs=["/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"],
 libraries=["systemd"]
```

add them as arguments in the `setup.py` file while creating the `Extension`

hope this helps whoever needs it.